# fastify-multer, testing with Postman, request.files is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, multer, fastify

I'm attempting to create an api that consumes multipart/form-data using fastify. I'm using the `fastify-multer` plugin in an attempt to send files so that I can pass them through to another 3rd party api. Right now I'm simply trying to test with Postman, but when I make a post request with png/pdf files, `request.files` is undefined. I've tried following along with the `fastify-multer` docs, with a slight modification. I'm keeping my routes in a separate directory and then using `fastify-autoload` to bring them in. `server.js` is registering all of my plugins, and I have an `index.js` that starts the server (and is working fine, so I didn't include it below). Here is what my setup looks like:

`server.js`

```js
const path = require('path')
const fp = require('fastify-plugin')
const autoload = require('fastify-autoload')
const multer = require('fastify-multer')
const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() })

async function registerPlugins(server, config) {
  server
    .register(multer.contentParser)
    .register(require('fastify-cors'), config.cors)
    .register(require('fastify-helmet'))
    .register(require('fastify-sensible'))
    // auto-register all plugins
    .register(autoload, {
      dir: path.join(__dirname, 'plugins'),
      ignorePattern: /.*test.js/,
      options: config
    })
    // auto-register all routes
    .register(autoload, {
      dir: path.join(__dirname, 'routes'),
      ignorePattern: /.*test.js/,
      options: config
    })

  server.decorate('upload', upload)
}

module.exports = fp(registerPlugins)
```

`my.routes.js`

```js
const fp = require('fastify-plugin')
const { createMerchantSchema } = require('./schema')

async function myRoutes(server, options) {
  server.post(
    '/merchant/:merchantId/uploadAttachment',
    { preHandler: server.upload.array('files', 8) },
    async (request, reply) => {
      console.log('FILES:')
      console.log(request.files)

      return reply.code(200).send('SUCCESS')
    }
  )
}

module.exports = fp(myRoutes)
```

I won't trouble you with showing my directory structure, but I have 6 other routes (not shown here) that are working just fine, and the server starts with no errors. Here is the console output when I send `POST /merchant/12345/uploadAttachment`:

```sh
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
[1597110502609] INFO  (96323 on 7L6BHR2.agrium.com): Server listening at http://0.0.0.0:3333
[1597110502609] INFO  (96323 on 7L6BHR2.agrium.com): Server running at: http://0.0.0.0:3333
[1597110510972] INFO  (96323 on 7L6BHR2.agrium.com): incoming request
    reqId: 1
    req: {
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/merchant/123456/uploadAttachment",
      "hostname": "localhost:3333",
      "remoteAddress": "127.0.0.1",
      "remotePort": 51207
    }

FILES:
undefined

[1597110510981] INFO  (96323 on 7L6BHR2.agrium.com): request completed
    reqId: 1
    res: {
      "statusCode": 200
    }
    responseTime: 8.47090208530426
```

Postman doesn't seem to be sending anything but header data; the request is only 408b:
[image: Postman POST call]

I am not sending the `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` header on my own. Postman is smart enough to add that, and not providing it means I don't have to pass in my own boundary.

I'm really not sure what is going wrong here. Has anyone set up `fastify-multer` like this? Anything I'm missing? I'm pulling my hair out! Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Did you check if `server.upload.array('files', 8)` returns a function?

Comment: Yes, it shows as `[Function: multerPreHandler]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the creator of `fastify-multer`, Maksim Sinik, for helping me solve this silly issue. All credit goes to him. I found out that, in fact, `fastify-multer` works great with `fastify-autoload` and `fastify-plugin`. My issue was that in Postman, I wasn't allowing the auto-generated header `content-length` to be sent with the request:

[image: image of content-length header disabled]

Internally, `fastify-multer` uses npm module [type-is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/type-is) to help discover the type of the request. If `content-length` is not sent, `content-type` is not sent as `multipart/form-data` and the `type-is` `hasBody` method returns null, which causes `request.files` to be undefined.

Moral of the story: if you want to test `fastify-multer` (or any other multipart data processor for that matter) with Postman, you must ensure the auto-generated `content-length` AND `content-type` header are enabled (selected):

[image: image of content-type and content-length headers enabled]

I really hope this helps someone in the future. I was pulling my hair out! Thanks again to Maksim. You can find more of the work he's done on [Github](https://github.com/fox1t).